# Does copying data byte wise between types break strict aliasing?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

Suppose I have 2 types `A` and `B` with same size and I have two variables

```
A a = ... ; // Initialized to some constant of type A
B b;
```

If I copy the contents of `a` to `b` using something like -

```
assert(sizeof(A) == sizeof(B));
size_t t;
for( t=0; t < sizeof(A); t++){
    ((char*)&b)[t] = ((char*)&a)[t];
}
```

Does this break strict aliasing rules of C?
I know casting a pointer to `char*` and reading it is not UB but I am concerned about both the derefences involved in the assignment.

If this is not UB, can this be a valid way for type punning?

Comment: It's UB not due to strict aliasing (you don't have aliasing here, actually, except with `char*`, which is allowed). It's UB because you may have just filled B with a trap representation. The value represented by the bit pattern you copied officially leaves `b` in an indeterminate state, IIRC.

Comment: @StoryTeller if `B` is guaranteed to be a type that doesn't have a trap representation is this "OK"?

Comment: [Well, yeah](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.19.2). But the standard doesn't promise you any meaningful semantics.

Comment: @StoryTeller, if `A` and `B` are two struct types with exactly the same fields, can I expect the behaviour to be same as each field being copied individually. Because the standard guarantees that any implementation must have the same memory layout if two structures are defined with same members.

Comment: The standard does indeed guarantee it. I think you should be okay. The contents of any padding bits being copied will not interfere since they are merely unspecified. All corresponding members *will* get their values copied properly. As a side note, I think your loop should be replaced with a call to `memcpy`. It will require less casting (and in turn will look cleaner for it).

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, I would use `memcpy` in real use. It's just I wanted to highlight the cast of pointers here since my question was about strict aliasing. Anyway, thanks for answering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code does not violate aliasing rules. From the latest draft (n1570), §6.5 section 7:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
>   the following types:
>   — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>   — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>   — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the
>   object,
>   — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the
>   effective type of the object,
>   — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its
>   members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
>   — **a character type**

(emphasis mine)

> I am concerned about both the derefences involved in the assignment.

These dereferences **are** *accessing the stored value* using a *character type*.

Of course, you could still trigger *undefined behavior* if the representation of your `A` is not a valid representation for `B`.

Comment: I think this answer clears the confusion beyond any doubt. From a discussion above in comments (and also from your last line) it is clear that it won't be UB if `B` has no trap representation. But the standard doesn't guarantee anything about the semantics. But  if A and B are two struct types with exactly the same fields, can I expect the behavior to be same as each field being copied individually. Because the standard guarantees that any implementation must have the same memory layout if two structures are defined with same members.

Comment: In cases where the destination is known only by a pointer, 6.5p6 throws a spanner in the works.

Answer (score 1):

In cases where the destination has a declared type, there is no problem, but in cases where the destination is known only via pointer the Standard is ambiguous.  According to the absolutely horribly written 6.5p6, copying data using `memcpy` or `memmove`, or "as an array of character type" [whatever that means] will cause the Effective Type of the source to be applied to the destination.  The Standard doesn't specify what one must do to copy a sequence of bytes without the operation being regarded as copying an "array of character type".

Comment: In my question the destination type is complete since I imposed the condition that size of A and B are equal. But thanks for this insight. It is rare to see that the standard is so vague about something ( in my experience ).

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: The authors of the Standard recognized that different applications fields need to use aliasing in different ways, and thus figured that any quality compiler suitable for any particular field should support aliasing in cases which were appropriate for that field *whether the Standard required it or not*, so there was no need to delve into every possible corner case.  Still, 6.5p6 is truly horrible because it offers useful opportunities for real optimization but major opportunities for mischief.

Comment: I don't think that's correct: Neither having a *declared type* nor an *effective type* is only possible for *allocated objects* ... once they have an *effective type* it will stay. If you want, I could try to find relevant passages in the standard tomorrow.

Comment: To clarify by example: If you would have `B *b = malloc(sizeof(B));` and then copy `a` through a `char *` there, you would indeed have a problem, because `*b` would get the *effective type* `char`. But with `B b;`, there can't be a problem.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: In the particular scenario where the destination is a simply-declared object, there is no problem.  In the scenario where the destination is known only by a pointer [a situation which applies to allocated objects, but also to cases where a function receives a pointer from somewhere else], the wheels fall off in cases where a bytewise copy is used for type conversion.

Comment: @supercat I strongly disagree with "*but also to cases where a function receives a pointer from somewhere else*" -- in that case, there is already an *effective type*, and the effective type doesn't change. As I said, I'll look up the relevant citations tomorrow.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Both GCC and Clang interpret the phrase about objects with declared type as being applicable only in cases where the compiler can see what the type is.  The rule would be impractical if it were interpreted as applying to pointers to objects which are declared in outside code, since the compiler would have no way of knowing what those types might be.  The notion that storage should have an "effective type" which is altered by writing to it should be recognized as being a truly horrible and broken model, since what should really matter is whether an object will be accessed...

Comment: ...multiple times via the same lvalue, with no evidence that it will be accessed via any other means between those accesses.  Presently, if `*p` and `*q` are pointers of different types, a compiler must (under C99 rules) generally keep writes to them in order whether or not there is any evidence of aliasing, because in case of aliasing each write would set the Effective Type, and whichever one happens last must "win".  A rule based upon evidence of aliasing would allow reordering when no evidence exists, but allow programmers to use most of the useful semantics of  `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

Comment: Consider the first sentence "*The effective type of an object for an access to its stored value is the declared type of the object, if any*" together with the footnote "*Allocated objects have no declared type*". This is in fact the *only* possibility for an object not having a declared type. If you pass a pointer to a function, you're either using `void *`, the correct declared type, or a wrong type. This last option is already a violation. So I don't see how this should be a problem for a compiler. It can safely assume the pointers don't alias.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: I meant passing a pointer *into* a function.  If a function with a pointer-type parameter is called by outside code, it will generally have no way of knowing with certainty what types of object could be identified by the pointer.  It would be reasonable for a function that receives an argument of type `float*` and dereferences it without a typecast to expect that it would identify something of type `float*`, but given e.g. `uint32_t float_as_bits(float *fp) { return *(uint32_t*)fp;}` it shouldn't take a genius compiler to realize that `fp` should be presumed...

Comment: ...capable of identifying either a `float` or an `uint32_t` when it is dereferenced, since nothing else happens to the object in question between the cast and the dereference.  Nothing in the rationale suggests that quality compilers for platforms where such conversions could be useful should ignore such evidence of aliasing.  More likely, such cases would have been seen as sufficiently *obvious* that compiler writers should be able to figure them out themselves whether the Standard mandates it or not.